# Table Query for id and other attribute LIKE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

I'm making this query:

```
User.where("id = ? AND nome LIKE ?",id,nome)
```

and it returns nil when it should return a value.

If UI do the query for the id alone it works and for the name alone it works.

Can I do this another way? Or am I just way way off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add wildcard character `%` around the `nome`.

Try like this:

```
User.where("id = ? AND nome LIKE ?", id, "%#{nome}%")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another query:

```
User.find_by_sql(["select * from users where id = ? AND nome LIKE ?"],id,"%#{nome}%" ")
```